# Can channel selections be codified in `conda_build_config.yaml`?

Tags: conda-build

I'd love to be able to codify my channel selections in my `conda_build_config.yaml` file.
I tried including this text in that file:

```yaml
channels:
  - dbanas
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
```

but to no avail.
(I still had to include: `-c dbanas -c defaults -c conda-forge` on my `conda build` command line, in order to get a successful build.)

**Is there any way to codify channel selections in the `conda_build_config.yaml` file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Technically*, additional channels can be specified in Conda Forge (via [`channel_sources` key](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/announcements.html#defaults-channel-is-now-dropped-when-building-conda-forge-packages) in `conda-forge.yml`), but **practically, it is almost never allowed**. [Here is an example](https://github.com/conda-forge/pymde-feedstock/pull/11) where we tried to use `pytorch` channel in order to support Windows for PyMDE. The Pull Request and build rendered fine, but then the CI blocked the upload of the packages to Anaconda Cloud.

Generally, recipes must use only `conda-forge` channel. A principal motivation is that this allows `conda install -c conda-forge <pkg>` to just work. All the questions on SO where users try `conda install -c bioconda <pkg>` and it fails are practical examples of why it is troublesome to depend on multiple channels, especially when Anaconda Cloud has no support for showing users something like `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda <pkg>` (the proper command).